# Different IO for query using two likes conditions vs 1 like condition with a range

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I was wondering why when I get statistics on my queries:
one query with two like conditions has different statistics than a 1 like condition query that uses a range too contain both like conditions.
There is a different logical read count even though they are functionally equivalent from what I can see.

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON 
SELECT cust_id from orders where item_id like '12%' OR item_id like '14%'
--(17938 row(s) affected)
--Table 'orders'. Scan count 2, logical reads 91, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
SELECT cust_id from orders where item_id like '1[24]%'
--(17938 row(s) affected)
--Table 'orders'. Scan count 1, logical reads 169, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Comment: Have you examined the execution plans? I'd be surprised if the query optimizer turned both of those into identical queries. Note that statistics are nontrivial: you need to ensure that each test starts will all of the appropriate buffers flushed, nothing of interest cached, system quiescent, ... .

Comment: In the Xml for the plans it looks like there is different CompileMemory, and different CachedPlan sizes. <ScalarOperator ScalarString="&apos;11þ&apos;"> <Const ConstValue="&apos;11þ&apos;"/> –
Also a logical operator got introduced along with another ScalarOperator for the second like condition in the second query.
I cannot clear all of those things out at the moment but will if I have the time.